# In Ember, how can I find out the exact URL a call like store.query will hit?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

When debugging my API, I want to know, for a given line of code

```
store.query('foo', {filter: ...})
```

exactly what URL this causes Ember to hit. Currently, to find this out, I just open devtools and look for the request in the network tab.

This isn't ideal because:

- it's harder to find the relevant network request if there are a lot of them
- I have to do a whole refresh and wait for the page to load

Is there a better way, maybe a programmatic one using a low-level API?

I'm looking for something like:

```
store.buildRequest('query', 'foo', {filter: ...}).url()
```

Answer (score 0):

In application adapter, override `urForQuery`.
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_urlForQuery

```
console.log(this._buildURL(modelName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this exact method by extending the store service and calling the [buildURL](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.7.0/addon/-private/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L54) method on your model's adapter.

```
// services/store.js
export default Ember.Service.extend({

  buildRequestURL(requestType, modelName, data) {
    let id, query;

    // determine if a query or an id
     if (Ember.typeOf(data) === 'object') {
      query = data;
    } else {
      id = data;
    }

    return this.adapterFor(modelName) // retrieve the adapter for your model                     
      .buildURL(                      // build the url for your request
        modelName, 
        id, 
        null, 
        requestType, 
        query
      ); 
  }
});
```

The `buildURL` internally calls a specific url building method based on the request type. (`urlForFindRecord`, `urlForQuery`, .etc)

You would use it pretty much identically to what you suggested (just without the `.url()` at the end):

```
// get the url for for store.query('foo', { filter: ... })
const urlQuery = store.buildRequestURL('query', 'foo', { filter: ... });

// get the url for store.findRecord('bar', 1);
const urlFind = store.buildRequestURL('findRecord', 'bar', 1);

// ...
```